# Access ubuntu machine via VNC server

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access

I am trying to access my Ubuntu machine remotely through a VNC service.  I have configured the machine and am successfully able to open a VNC session when pointing to my own machine locally.  Remotely however I cannot establish a connection but am able to SSH in.

I'm using remmima (sp?) client for the VNC service.  I think it has something to do with the machine I'm trying to access locking the screen after a period of inactivity (ie. when I travel to the remote machine to access it).

Not able to find this answer anywhere, so any tips would be appreciated.

System:
Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit
Using the stock Desktop viewer to configure the VNC session.

Comment: Have you forwarded the correct ports? Unfortunately, if you didn't, we can't help since that's router-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer here:

[Remote desktop for multiple users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247115/remote-desktop-for-multiple-users/287371#287371)

X2go and ssh Works with better support and features for linux remote desktop. (Like, file sharing, clipboard sharing, sound over net, web client, etc).

There are other ways to do it, but it worked for me, so I post it.