# Remote desktop for multiple users

Tags: remote-desktop

This is an old question.
Is there something like remote desktop but have multiple users logging into their own desktop?
Well as at home windows xp remote desktop.

Comment: Look into VNC. That should be it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [x2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:repositories:ubuntu), seems to be a good project with good support.

I had problem with athentication mentioned [here](http://john.wesorick.com/2011/11/issues-installing-x2go.html). This will happen if you SSH into the server before installing x2go. SSH by default likes ecdsa keys, and x2go doesn't. These step fixed it:

1. On the server, edit the ssh config:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```

   (Remmember, Ctrl+O saves changes and Ctrl+X exits from nano text editor)
2. Then comment out this line with a #:

   ```
   #HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
   ```
3. Now restart ssh:

   ```
   sudo service ssh restart
   ```
4. On your client you need to remove your old key. I just removed all of them.

   ```
   rm .ssh/known_hosts
   ```

**Gnome-session-fallback seems to be needed**

Please add this package on server:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

And then configure custom desktop with gnome-session-fallback on client

Another amazing feautre from x2go, is [this](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:advanced:x2goplugin).

I have tried it and changed html file localhost > my.ip.addre.ss and command= from xfce to gnome-session-fallback
Also change quality and colors from 16m to 2m.
Everything works great, now I'm posting it with a remote desktop session from a web browser with plugin and also copy and paste works!  Sound works through net!!! Just very complete solution.

@Wolfer: I don't know how to have multile users remote desktop with VNC, do you have any information about it? link to some help?

Answer (score 1):

Recently i have used remote desktop multi users.. this is how to configure.. 
[ubuntu 14.10 multiple Simultaneous independent remote (desktop like ) connections](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581979/ubuntu-14-10-multiple-simultaneous-independent-remote-desktop-like-connection)