# xrdp from Windows 7

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

I installed xrdp on my new Ubuntu Server 12.xx I saw a video that talked about creating a `.xsession` because of the 3D and 2D desktop. But it didn't work.

If I take the .xsession out it opens a empty desktop with no icons on it.

This is the content of the `.xsession` file.

```
gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running 12.10 or 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer here:

[Remote desktop for multiple users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247115/remote-desktop-for-multiple-users/287371#287371)

X2go and ssh Works with better support and features for linux remote desktop. (Like, file sharing, clipboard sharing, sound over net, web client, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but the answer might be useful to somebody out there.

- if you are running ubuntu 12.04, you can use the command
  **gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d** in the .xsession and this should work.
- if you are running **ubuntu 12.10** and you are using the command
  **gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d**, ***this will not work*** because ubuntu-2d was not available anymore. If you are planning to use ubuntu 12.10, you should add the following command in your .xsession file **gnome-session
     --session=gnome-fallback**  instead of **gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d**
- If you want to use xrdp with **Ubuntu version higher than 12.10**, you
  would need to install an alternate desktop
  (xfce,mate-desktop,kde,lxde..you choose) and update accordingly your
  .xsession file..

You can find detailed information about using xrdp and ubuntu 14.04 following this link (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5382).

Hope this help