# Windows to Ubuntu via rdp: mounting local drives?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, file-sharing, xrdp

As some of you may know, RDP in Windows allows the client to make its drives available to the host or target machine. I have done that with no problems in the case of Windows-Windows and Linux-Windows (rdesktop), but I can't seem to find a way to do it for Windows-Linux. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve drive redirection with xRDP solution.  xRDP allows you to use your windows remote desktop client and to remotely connect to your Ubuntu computer.  xRDP needs to be installed on the Linux machine. So, xRDP software is the equivalent of Remote Desktop in Linux.

xRDP package from Ubuntu repository does not provide drive redirection. To have drive redirection, you will need to compile the xrdp binaries... The drive redirection seems to be supported in xRDP version 0.6 or later (if you compile the xRDP package)

You can view a quick demo of drive redirection with xRDP [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9229)

The following [link](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9225) provides a scripted custom installation of xRDP. This script will compile the xRDP with the necessary switch to include drive redirection feature in xRDP.

hope this is helpful

Comment: are you a xrdp developer? you should mention the Ubuntu and xrdp versions that make this possible

Comment: Hello no I'm not a xrdp developper. ...If you download from github the xrdp package 0.6 and higher, if you compile it with the appropriate options (i.e.  --enable-fuse), drive redirection should be working

Comment: "_xRDP package from Ubuntu repository does not provide drive redirection_" -- **this is not true.** The `xrdp` package in any modern distributions have the `--enable-libfuse` flag for building it, and it does clipboard & drive redirection (sharing).

Answer (score 3):

ssh is better supported for remote file sharing, try with winscp from windows to connect to linux machine file system. 
You must have installed ssh on server.

You can also try my answer from:
[Remote desktop for multiple users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247115/remote-desktop-for-multiple-users/287371#287371) 
To have full support with x2go, I have tried it and works very well for lot of features with remote desktop.

Answer (score 2):

While it isn't xrdp, ThinLinc allows you to share local drives to the server. It could be worth a try if you can't get xrdp working!

(full disclosure: I'm a ThinLinc dev)